# Iphone backup for my application

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have an iphone app with tons of coredata data. I am trying to implement a full backup method where i can get all of the data from the app and throw it to a webserver. I prefer to use json data for this format. Is there an easy way to dump all of the application data out of the system? or a method for backing up the data structures directly from in an app?

Answer (score 0):

You could just upload the persistent store file itself. That would grab everything.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up building something cool for this by grabbing the sqlite file and a web service. Everything seems to be good as long as connection is not broken. Let me know any questions on this in the future